# what is the alternative of javaScriptWindowObjectCleared() on new qt 5.10 ?javaScriptWindowObjectCleared is not recognized on qt 5.10

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Please help I want to port webkit to WebEngine but I have some problems with that, I have a signal javaScriptWindowObjectCleared() which is not recognized by new qt 5.10. What can help me in this case?

```
connect( this->page(), SIGNAL( javaScriptWindowObjectCleared() ), SLOT( OnPopulateJavaScriptObjec() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code sinppet may help you.

```
    QWebEngineScript toBeInjectedjs;
    toBeInjectedjs.setName("qwebchannel.js"); 
    toBeInjectedjs.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript::DocumentCreation); //important
    toBeInjectedjs.setRunsOnSubFrames(false);
    toBeInjectedjs.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript::MainWorld);
    toBeInjectedjs.setSourceCode(jsStr);  //jsStr is what your want to inject to page;
    scripts().insert(toBeInjectedjs); //scripts is a member function of QWebEnginePage.
```